# Why the size of the dumped file is much larger than influxDB data directory?

Tags: influxdb

My influxDB version is 1.8.10, and I use the following command to export the database

> influx_inspect export -compress -datadir "/var/lib/influxdb/data"
> -waldir "/var/lib/influxdb/wal" -out "influxdb_dump_out" -database "test" -start "2023-01-01T00:00:00Z"

the size of file `influxdb_dump_out` is much larger than the `/var/lib/influxdb` directory

the `/va/lib/influxdb` directory size

[image: influxdb dir]

the dumped database file

[image: dump]